# Java Converting binary sequence to char

Tags: java

I looked for this about an hour now, but couldn't get any advise specific to my problem. What I'd like to do is take a string of 0's and 1's and manipulate a char that it fits the given String pattern. For example:

```
    char c = 'b'
    String s = "00000000 01100001";
```

Now I'd like to manipulate the bits in c, so that they match the bit pattern specified in s. As result c would be printed as 'a' (if I'm not completely wrong about it). Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
      String s = "00000000 01100001";
      String[] w = s.split(" ");
      char c = (char)(Integer.parseInt(w[0], 2) * 256 + Integer.parseInt(w[1], 2));
```

This allows for the leading zeroes of each byte to be omitted. If you know they're there, you can just replace the space out of the string and use a single `parseInt()` call:

```
      char c = (char)Integer.parseInt(s.replace(" ", ""), 2);
```

Comment: I would have done `s.replaceAll(" ", "");` and parseInt that. valueOf might create an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
char a = (char) Integer.parseInt("0000000001100001", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks all of you for the instant help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To do the conversion from binary string to Integer, use parseInt with the 2nd argument as 2.

```
int temp = Integer.parseInt("01100001", 2);
```

You can modify with binary operators (&,|,^), but if what you really want is to just assign a variable, you can do it with casts.

```
char c = 'c';    
System.out.println((char)(c&temp));

System.out.println((char)temp);
```